# jquery - Disable Button and Input with dynamic names

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the a table structure similar to this, but a lot of other nested stuff above and below.  I need to disable the button and link (or possibly change the button visibility, instead of disabling it?).

The button ID and anchor names are dynamic (value 10, below) and I've tried everything I can think of to grab these elements from the table and disable, but nothing seems to work:

```
<tr>
<td class="t-last">
<button id="btnEdit10" class="ui-state-active ui-corner-all button-outer"    
onclick="ClientValues(10);">Edit</button>
<a name="lnkDelete10" class="cursor_hand" onclick="DeleteIt(10,200);">
<u>Delete</u>
</a>
</td>
<tr>
<td class="t-last">
<button id="btnEdit17" class="ui-state-active ui-corner-all button-outer"    
onclick="ClientValues(17);">Edit</button>
<a name="lnkDelete17" class="cursor_hand" onclick="DeleteIt(17,200);">
<u>Delete</u>
</a>
</td>
```

I've guessing regular expressions will be my best bet, but I still haven't gotten it to work.  This is what I'm trying to use to disable the button, but I can't access it:

```
$('btnEdit10').attr("disabled", true); //after looping to the control
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I wasn't very clear in my question.  I'm trying to disable every button that starts with "btnEdit" and every link that starts with "lnkDelete".

Comment: Are you trying to disable everything that starts with `btnEdit`, or just `btnEdit10`, and if so, where does `10` come from ?

Comment: I'm trying to disable everything that starts with "btnEdit" or, for the links, starts with "lnkDelete".  I'd like to then loop through and disable them all (both links and buttons).

Comment: That's what I figured, was waiting for a response to post an answer for like 15 minutes? Looks like those buttons belong to jQuery UI, and if so they are possibly dynamic, which means they don't exist on pageload. After the buttons are added to the DOM, my answer below should work.

Comment: You are correct, they're from jQuery UI.  I learned quite a few things from you today Adeneo -- you are awesome!  ...and have no idea how much you saved my arse!

Comment: adeneo -- Do you have any more information (a link perhaps) on jQuery UI and it's interaction and load in relation to the DOM?  I'm doing research now b/c it's already causing other problems.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable everything that starts with "btnEdit", use the "attributes starts with" selector :

```
$('[id^="btnEdit"]').prop("disabled", true);
```

or for both:

```
$('[id^="btnEdit"], [id^="lnkDelete"]').prop("disabled", true);
```

**EDIT:**

or maybe:

```
$('[id^="btnEdit"]').prop("disabled", true);
$('[id^="lnkDelete"]').attr("onclick", "");
```

Comment: The button disabling works perfect!  But for some reason the link isn't being disabled.  It previously only had the 'name' attribute, so I added an identical 'id' attribute, but it's still not working.  The onclick event still fires.

Comment: You can't really disable an anchor, as it has no diasbled attribute! I was sure what it was that you where trying to do, but if it is to disable the click function, you would have to remove that. I'll update my answer?

Comment: Wow, I wish so bad that I could thank you in person!  It works flawlessly!

Comment: @Panuvin - no problem, just happy to help!

Answer (score 4):

If I understand it well, something like this

```
 $('#btnEdit' + dynamic_part).attr("disabled", disable);
```

Update:

you can select all ids start with `btnEdit` like this

```
 $("[id^=btnEdit]").attr("disabled", disable);
```

Comment: It's better to use `prop` than `attr`.  But +1 anyway. :)

Comment: The part I can't figure out is how to get that "dynamic_part".  It's usually a number, but I'd like to test a button with anything after it: id="btnEdit3249939493394x".  How do I get that "dynamic_part"?  Sorry, I'm very new to jQuery and appreciate your help.

Comment: from where you get that number?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to disable a specific button, then you can do something like this...

```
$('#btnEdit10').attr("disabled", disable);
```

Otherwise if you want control a group of buttons to disable, you can do what InTry mentioned and setup a variable next to the selector name...

```
$('#btnEdit' + my_number).attr("disabled", disable);
```

and store the appropriate number value(s) into that variable (my_number) with some simple coding.

Comment: The dynamic number is what I can't figure out.  How can I disable every button that starts with "btnEdit" or link that starts with "lnkDelete"?

Comment: Yes, adeneo is a freakin' life-saver!